# Checking (if statement) table tr element if display is none

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a specific tr (row) of the table has a none display value. If it does then I want it to execute some different code for me:

```
  if $('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display == "none" {
    $('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display = "none";
    $('.table')[0].rows[4].style.display = "none";
  }else{
    $('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display = "table-row";
    $('.table')[0].rows[4].style.display = "table-row";
  }
```

I tried this but I am getting the error `ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at the if line.

I tried setting this line to a variable and then checking if this is variable is == to "none" but I was still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its supposed to be `if ( CONDITION )` instead of `if CONDITION`

Comment: This is not valid javascript syntax. [If statement needs parentheses](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If statements require parentheses around the condition.

```
if ($('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display == "none") {
    $('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display = "none";
    $('.table')[0].rows[4].style.display = "none";
}
else {
    $('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display = "table-row";
    $('.table')[0].rows[4].style.display = "table-row";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
 if $('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display == "none" {
```

To:

```
 if ($('.table')[0].rows[5].style.display === "none") {
```